# Returning the ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a function

```
function chkLogin() {
    $.get("setAlert.php", function (data) {
        $(".result").html(data);
        if (data == 'Not logged in') {
            alert("not logged in.");
        } else {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
}
```

**setAlert.php**

```
if (!isset($login_session)) { 
    return "Not logged in";
   }
   else{
 return "logged in";
}
```

and it alerts success because data is blank.
So how can i set data to "Logged in " or "Not logged in" ? 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to return anything

just use `echo`

```
if (!isset($login_session)) {
    echo "Not logged in";
} else {
    echo "logged in";
}
```

Read [jQuery Ajax call tutorial](http://www.cleverweb.nl/php/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial/)

---

To redirect user if he is not logged in use [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

```
$.get("setAlert.php", function (data) {
    $(".result").html(data);
    if (data == 'Not logged in') {
        window.location = "index.php"; // redirect page if user not logged in
    } else {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

Comment: But if it is not logged in, i want to redirect to the login page.how can i do this ?i cant write header function in if block.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check login.
usually use the cookie to check.
you could call the php cookie method to save cookie, and check the cookie data on client side.

[sample](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

try to handle response with json data.

call the ajax with json

```
function chkLogin() {
$.get("setAlert.php", function (data) {
    $(".result").html(data);
    if (data.status == true) {
        alert("success");
    } else {
        alert("not logged in.");
    }
},"json");
}
```

Modify setAlert.php

```
$result = array();
if (!isset($login_session)) { 
$result['status'] = false;}
else{ $result['status'] = true;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```